# Task.Factory.StartNew Start a new Thread as Administrator

Tags: asp.net

I running VS as Administrator to get access to the network directories.
When I am calling a method from `Task.Factory` the new thread runs not As 'Administrator'...

Is there a way to start the new thread as Administrator ?

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. `Task.Factory.StartNew`doesn't start any threads at all. The work passed to `StartNew` or `Task.Run` is executed by a thread that comes from a thread pool. And finally, VS is the IDE, not your application. The permissionions you use to start the IDE process aren't transferred to the application it compiles and spawns.

Comment: You need to start *your application* as an administrator, if you want that application to have elevated privileges.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am running VS as administrator. do you know a way to use Administrator privileges with the new thread (the one from the thread pool)? thanks